# errors not shown in Firebug console with dojo/when promise

Tags: debugging, dojo, console, promise

Newbie to Dojo. I don't understand why js errors are not **written** to the firebug console when happening in the resolved promise handler of the **dojo/when** function. With synchronous code, errors are written. However when the error happens, the erroneous line is shown in the Firebug script view. I'm using Dojo 1.8 FF 19.0 and Firebug 1.11.2.

Comment: Can you post code, errors and/or a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: A fiddle would be great.  What about a breakpoint.  Are you able to halt at that line in firebug?

Comment: This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ5jW/1/). Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

there has to be a try catch block somewhere along the code, that prevents dojo/when to throw errors.

You can add that functionality by adding a try catch block by yourself, check out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kYMKF/1/

```
    try{
        should.bombAndLogAnErrorInFirebug(); //this does not log an error in Firebug! Why?
    } catch(e) {
            alert("error");
        }
```